# insert from table1 into table2 where time difference in value input on table 1 is greater than 5 minute

Tags: mysql

EDIT: I probably should have stated im trying to input the beacon data where the next data input of the same beacon is greater than 5 minutes

im having issue's inserting value from table1 into table2 where there is a greater time input difference between data input on table 1 where the beacon matches.

e.g. the data input gap between ID 7 and ID 8 is larger than 5 minutes but the query im using below returns no data

```
INSERT INTO table
(`beacon`, `zone`, `mac`, `date`, `time`, `id`)

VALUES
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:21:33","1"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:21:43","2"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:21:53","3"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:03","4"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:13","5"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:32","6"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:33","7"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:30:00","8"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:30:33","9"),
("8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:30:35","10");
```

the query that inst returning any results im not sure if i have missed a bit or just written it incorrectly

```
select a.beacon, a.zone, a.mac, a.date from table a
join table b
on b.id = (select min(id) from table where id > a.id)
where TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.time, b.time)) > 300;
```

im trying to insert data from 1 mysql into table into another where the data input on table 1 and where the beacons match is greater than 5 minutes between data inputs into database.table1

e.g.

```
"8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:21:33","1"),
"8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:33","1"),
"8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:23:33","1"), (Ref 1)
value 8 stopped being inputted into database
"10","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:21:33","1"), 
"10","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:22:33","1"),
"10","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:25:33","1"),
value 8 started inputting into database
"8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:28:33","1"), (Ref 2)
"8","GREEN","EE6A6AF29B8E","2018-11-13","16:28:33","1"),
```

the difference between REF 1 and REF 2 is 5 minutes so insert value 8 into data base

only compare the data where the beacon is the same ( beacon being the 1st column)

so even though there is data input less than 5 minutes before Reference 2 because the beacon is different to Reference 2 it doesn't take this string into account.

Comment: Is table 1 the same as table a?

Comment: isn't `id` ambiguous in the on clause?

Comment: @Strawberry yes table a is table 1 and nickellis i get no error for ID being ambiguous

Comment: If you're still struggling then I suggest you see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is the query resolved ? are you trying to insert data or select data ? some more explanation will be handy.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have updated the question so hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton correct me if I am wrong. You are trying to select all those rows from Table 1 which has atleast 5 minutes gap from the previous row, and then insert all of them into Table 2 ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya in a way my current system gets around 300000 strings of data a day and im looking a reducing this by only inputting data into a filter table when the beacon comes into the system so im trying to find a way to input a beacon from table 1 to table 2 where it hasnt been seen in table a for more than 5 minutes since it was last seen

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton it looks like a `AFTER INSERT ON table1` trigger problem

Comment: can i ask why it would be an after insert problem the issue im having is when i run the query even though there is data with a larger time interval of 5 minute between data inputs it returns no data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you mimimise your query to this and check.

```
select a.beacon, a.zone, a.mac, a.date from table a
join table b on b.id<a.id
and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.time, b.time)) >300;
```

Basically you need those rows which are less than table a's row and those that satisfy the condition.

Comment: if i do it this way it return data but does b.id not need to be larger than a.id